# How do I parse S-expressions into a data structure in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and could use some guidance.

The challenge: take an S-expression and parse it into a record.

Where I have succeeded: I can take a file and read it into a parsed String. 
Yet, using parsing Text to DFA s.t

```
 let 
        toDFA :: [L.Text] -> EntryDFA
        toDFA t =
           let [q,a,d,s,f] = t
           in EntryDFA { 
               state = read q
              ,alpha = read a
              ,delta = read d
              ,start = read s
              ,final = read f }
```

returns this error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘L.Text’ with ‘[Char]’
  Expected type: String
    Actual type: L.Text
```

There must be a more idiomatic approach.

Comment: Your full code is missing imports it seems. Also your do-block seems to end with a `let` which is not allowed AFAIK. 
Why are you using `Text` at all? There is a splitOn that works for strings in `Data.List.Split` in the split package. I don't think using read the way you do will work though.

Comment: @JonasDuregård Text is definitely the right type for reading source files.

Comment: There are generally two approaches to parsing in Haskell: parser combinators and parser generators. Google should take you through the next few steps from there once you know these keywords. A tutorial on either tech is much too large to be a good topic for SO, I think.

Comment: @Cubic 1) That seems a bit oversimplified. 2) This code doesn't appear to read the source file as `Text`.

Comment: I am using the appropriate imports. I didn't include them, so full code is a bit misleading. I apologize. I was really looking for a way to resolve the issues between String and Text, or how to resolve the error code. From what I understood, Text is the best way to handle source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` is a partial function with type `Read a => String -> a`, which throws an exception on parsing failure. Normally you want to avoid it (use `readMaybe` instead if you have a string). `String` and `L.Text` are different types, which is why you're getting an error.

Your sample code is missing an extra `)` after the `trans-func`.

I'm using the Megaparsec package which provides an easy way to work with parser combinators. The author of the library has written a longer tutorial [here](https://markkarpov.com/megaparsec/parsing-simple-imperative-language.html).

The basic idea is that `Parser a` is the type of a value that can parse something of type `a`. In `Text.Megaparsec` there are several functions which you can use (`parse`, `parseMaybe` etc.), to "run" the parser on a "stringy" data type (e.g. `String` or strict/lazy `Text`).

When you use `do` notation for `IO`, it means "do one action after another". Similarly, you can use `do` notation with `Parser`, it means "parse this one thing, then parse the next thing".

`p1 *> p2` means run the parser `p1`, run `p2` and return the result of running `p2`. `p1 <* p2` means run the parser `p1`, run `p2` and return the result of running `p1`. You can also look up documentation on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) in case you're having trouble understanding something.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns    #-}

-- In practice, many of these imports would be unqualified, but I've
-- opted for explicitness for clarity.
import Control.Applicative (empty, many, some, (<*), (*>))
import Control.Exception (try, IOException)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Data.Set (Set)
import Data.Text (Text)

import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import qualified Text.Megaparsec as MP
import qualified Text.Megaparsec.Char as MPC
import qualified Text.Megaparsec.Char.Lexer as MPCL

type Q = Text
type E = Char

data EntryDFA = EntryDFA
  { state :: Set Q
  , alpha :: Set E
  , delta :: Set (Q,E,Q)
  , start :: Q
  , final :: Set Q
  } deriving Show

inputFile = "foo.sexp"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- read file and check for exception instead of checking if
  -- it exists and then trying to read it
  result <- try (TIO.readFile inputFile)
  case result of
    Left e -> print (e :: IOException)
    Right txt -> do
      case MP.parse dfaParser inputFile txt of
        Left e -> print e
        Right dfa -> print dfa

type Parser = MP.Parsec () Text

-- There are no comments in the S-exprs, so leave those empty
spaceConsumer :: Parser ()
spaceConsumer = MPCL.space MPC.space1 empty empty

symbol :: Text -> Parser Text
symbol txt = MPCL.symbol spaceConsumer txt

parens :: Parser a -> Parser a
parens p = MP.between (symbol "(") (symbol ")") p

setP :: Ord a => Parser a -> Parser (Set a)
setP p = do
  items <- parens (p `MP.sepBy1` (symbol ","))
  return (Set.fromList items)

pair :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser (a, b)
pair p1 p2 = parens $ do
  x1 <- p1
  x2 <- symbol "," *> p2
  return (x1, x2)

stateP :: Parser Text
stateP = do
  c <- MPC.letterChar
  cs <- many MPC.alphaNumChar
  return (T.pack (c:cs))

dfaParser :: Parser EntryDFA
dfaParser = do
  () <- spaceConsumer
  (_, state) <- pair (symbol "states") (setP stateP)
  (_, alpha) <- pair (symbol "alpha") (setP alphaP)
  (_, delta) <- pair (symbol "trans-func") (setP transFuncP)
  (_, start) <- pair (symbol "start") valP
  (_, final) <- pair (symbol "final") (setP valP)
  return (EntryDFA {state, alpha, delta, start, final})
  where
    alphaP :: Parser Char
    alphaP = MPC.letterChar <* spaceConsumer
    transFuncP :: Parser (Text, Char, Text)
    transFuncP = parens $ do
      s1 <- stateP
      a <- symbol "," *> alphaP
      s2 <- symbol "," *> stateP
      return (s1, a, s2)
    valP :: Parser Text
    valP = fmap T.pack (some MPC.digitChar)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. I am familiar with parsing, just not in Haskell. Coming from Python and C++, the handling of Data Types is my biggest impasse. A lot of my issues are with implementation, syntax, etc. Using String explicitly left me with issues where read q would fail when q is a parsed [Char], where [[Char]] looked like [\"states q\",\"alphabet e\", ... ]. And using Lazy.Text, which seems like the proper way to deal with consuming strings, lead to IO issues and the above error. And Hoogle is amazing. Thanks again.